# Devise needs cornfirmation mail after changing email address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using devise with rails3.1
Now I'd like devise to send confirmation mail after user changed his email address.
Is there any good way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did some google: [Re-confirm changed email address Options](http://groups.google.com/group/plataformatec-devise/browse_thread/thread/0ccd1d20625dc00c?pli=1)

maybe "MissingHandle's" post could be helpful

Comment: Thanks for the reply:) Unfortunately, it seems that only replaces current email field and require confirmation. What I really want is, temporary email field and it keeps there until he click on the link in new mail. After click, real email address will be replaced by temporary mail address. :)